# Creation Myth Development Help

Tags: worldbuilding-process, mythology, written-material

C.W Lewis's Narnia and J.R.R Tolkien's Middle-Earth series all had creation myths for their characters to believe.
I want to have a go for one of my projects but I'm stuck.
I would like suggestions, What do creation myths involve? What themes do I need to remember to put into one?

Comment: A creation myth, to be satisfactory, needs to fit some important aspect of the setting very closely. So we can't do anything with what you've given us, but you probably can get started if you look at the problem the right way. What's characteristic of your setting? Why is it like that? Do you have an in-setting reason why it's that way? A creation myth gives you a chance to plug such holes.

Comment: This is too broad for the format. However, once you get a bit more reputation, you'll be able to join us on the [chat], where such discussions may take place.

Comment: I would recommend this book.  It distills the common elements from world myths and religions regarding heroes and deities.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hero_with_a_Thousand_Faces

Comment: Actually a few of his books would be good reads, check out the "works" section:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Campbell

Comment: I don't think the topic is too broad for a precise answer. OP is seeking guidelines for the development of creation-myths in his setting. The question is clear in meaning and direction. All good answers are supposed to be directed towards the same purpose => explaining how creation myths originate and which factors facilitate them. Voting for reopening.

Comment: I like the subject, but as others have said, your question is too broad. If you build upon something, and then need help on specific parts that you'd wish to elaborate or expand on, then we may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Creation myths need to include an idea of the structure of the world - its size, the sky, the seas - who made it, and how. The why isn't usually important, it's assumed that creating worlds is what creators *do*.

The Wikipedia articles on [Creation Myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_myth) and [List of Creation Myths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_creation_myths) have lots of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you want the creators to be? are they(he) good? bad? smart? stupid? creative? boring? mischievous? cleaver? What do they value? Your creation story should be written in such a way that it helps the reader understand the creators.

As a side I try to create worlds with multiple creation stories (each one with various different yet with the basic story the same) I know which one is true but a never let my readers know.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do this, you need to make some basic determinations about your world.

Is it flat or is it a sphere (or something else entirely)?  Is the sun a ball of plasma and gas or a great crystal in the sky?  Is the sun the center of the universe or does the universe centered on your world?

All of these questions and more need to be answered first.  Following that, you need to develop an understanding of you god or gods (creators and lesser created).  When you understand your creators well enough, you will know better how they would create the world.

One key will be that ultimate power will need to be removed from your world or limitations placed on the creators.  For example, Tolkien's creator acted as a passive creator who only intervened occasionally.  I've not read the whole Cronicles of Narnia series; however, I did see that the Lion was not invulnerable and nor is he all powerful (as he wouldn't have had to wait for the children to find their way to Narnia to move against the Witch).

Probably the key is that something should go wrong during the creation.  Something the limited powers in the world did not anticipate.  In Tolkien, we aren't talking about Illuvatar, but the Valar.  They did not foresee the discord of Melkor.  In Narnia, the arrival of the Witch during the birth of Narnia was the unexpected event.  Both of these events set the stage for the chaos that would ensue.

Answer (score 1):

The examples you give are not creation myths as such, they are background stories for the setting written in the format of a creation myth. So you you should write, design, and use them as any other background story you give to characters, places, or important factions, but using mythological language and conventions.

Formatting them as myths is **not** really necessary though. Wizards or long lived races might very well describe the creation in perfectly factual terms, just like modern science does. Elves might write it up as a song. Dwarves might make a drinking song out of it.

It might help to think your setting as a character with its own features and personality and start from that. Giving your settings distinct personality is a step many authors forget. Often it might be easier to model it as a family of characters corresponding to different aspects of the development of your setting. And yes, that is very similar to a pantheon of gods, and there is a reason for that similarity, so you should make sure your gods and setting match in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

Creation myths also, sometimes, have a kernel of truth to them.

You have an incident, you tell your friend about it, he tells others, if it's a funny/sad/romantic etc enough story it is turned into a tale or a song sung through the centuries. Then you have people forgetting parts and adding extra verses. Someone comes along and purposely mixes two stories to create a newer fresher feel. These turn in legend, legends into myths and very soon (give or take a couple centuries) you have Joe Bob's fairly simple story of flirting and chasing an uninterested maiden into the masculine sun forever chasing after the moon, and in the chase, causing the earth to rotate and create day and night. Something to that effect.

Also, society and knowledge epps and flows, sometime reaching a peak before tumbling to some backward backwater. So you can have an educated people, searching the sky's and good medicine etc. They come up with theories of how the world was 'scienticially' created and then there is a loss of knowledge, a plague or religious war where all books are burnt etc so then the general populace can take what they remember and tell their kids and grandkids about how things used to be or how the world was thought to have been formed.

For example, the Christian bible's creation in Genesis is fairly accurate. Give or take a few days :). You have nothing, and from nothing you have everything. Light and dark is created. Then the land and seas are separated. Then plants are created. Then birds and fish and then animals are created. And then man is created. And then the creator stops.

You could take that to mean, you had nothing except the singularity. The singularity exploded and created the universe. Creating areas of darkness and light. Sun's and planets form. Seas are formed over the barren planets and slowly organic plant life starts to evolve. Fish and then birds evolve (the bible seems to have skipped over the whole dinosaur era but that is hardly surprising as the fossilised remains are spread out far and wide under rock). Animals (mammals) come along next, and the last to evolve is humans.

So you have however many billions of years old the universe is, described in just a few paragraphs in a religious book written billions of years after the fact (or roughly 6000years if you are in fact a creationist). That is one hell of a creation myth and I have no doubt it incorporates knowledge from several lost civilisations of mankind's past.